# How can I store the starting or ending date and time for my robot into firebase database real time?

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, arduino, robotics

we are implementing a Wheeled mobile robot
for indoor mapping using flutter for the mobile application, How can I store the starting or ending date and time for my robot into the firebase database in real-time?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Turn On/Off The Robot"),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Container(
      child: FlutterSwitch(
        width: 125.0,
        height: 55.0,
        valueFontSize: 25.0,
        toggleSize: 45.0,
        value: status,
        borderRadius: 30.0,
        padding: 8.0,
        showOnOff: true,
        onToggle: (val) {
          setState(() {
            status = val;
          });
        },
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

for example, this is the operation that I want to take its date by turning on or turning off the switch button, and then store in a **real-time** database

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Firebase Firestore, then cloud_firestore package has "Timestamp" class, that can be transformed to/from DatiTime objects. If you want to create a server-based timestamp in your database, use:

```
"myDateField": FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

This is a nice and easy solution but in case you don't have access to Timestamp class or want your date to be accessible from anywhere you can store it with **epoch timestamp**. In flutter you can call .millisecondsSinceEpoch to get the int value

```
int epochTimestamp = myDate.millisecondsSinceEpoch
```

And to create the DateTime object you can use:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(epochTimestamp)
```

Answering your question, you need to have 2 fields in your model:
**startDate** and **endDate** for example.

```
/// Get the initial starting time before the route
DateTime startDate = DateTime.now();
///
/// Some logic, where you wait until the end of the route
/// 
/// Get the ending time after all the logic/routing is complete
DateTime endDate = DateTime.now();
```

Comment: could you check my question again?

Comment: Just simply add the condition inside your onToggle, if ON - it's a starting date, if OFF - it's the finish date. To store the value in Firebase Real-Time Database (RTDB) refer to official documentation of Firebase RTDB or FlutterFire examples.